# jquery simplemodal multiple divs

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, simplemodal

I'm new to Jquery and using SimpleModal plugin to create popup windows.
I want to show only one content at a time on my popup window.
I use the same div link three times on my page but I want to show different content on them.

Now I get all three contents shown in the same window.
Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $('.bt-menu').click(function (e) {                             
    $('.content, .content2, .content3').modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
       dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
         dialog.data.hide();
         dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
           dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
           return false;
         });
       });
    }});
 });
});
```

So basically I have each content inside separate links which are using same class ('bt-menu').
But I would like to only show the content which is hidden in that link instead of showing all the hidden divs on the popup window.

I know the code is calling all the contents at the same time, just not sure how to change it??

Answer (score 0):

You could bind each to it's own modal object.

```
var makeModalObj = {onOpen: function (dialog) {
       dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
         dialog.data.hide();
         dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
           dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
           return false;
         });
       });
    }};

jQuery(function ($) {

  $('.bt-menu').click(function (e) {      

    $('.content').modal(makeModalObj);
    $('.content2').modal(makeModalObj);
    $('.content3').modal(makeModalObj);
  });
});
```